# how to add the tag corresponding to the clacluded factor in R?

Tags: r

I have this:

```
df<-data.frame(
  UNIT=c("PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP","PC_GDP"),
  GEO_DESC=c("NT","NT","NT","SW","SW","SW","ST","ST","ST","UK","UK","UK","US","US","US"),
  SECTFUND=c("BES","GOV","TOTAL","BES","GOV","TOTAL","BES","GOV","TOTAL","BES","GOV","TOTAL","BES","GOV","TOTAL"),
  x2008=c(NA,NA,1.62,NA,NA,3.47,1.85,0.62,2.71,0.73,0.49,1.61,1.76,0.84,2.77),
  x2009=c(0.75,0.68,1.67,2.02,0.92,3.40,NA,NA,NA,0.74,0.54,1.67,1.63,0.92,2.81)
)

df %>% 
group_by(SECTFUND) %>% 
  summarise(GEO_DESC = c(as.character(GEO_DESC), 'MEAN_top5'), SECTFUND = c(as.character(SECTFUND), 'result'), 
            across(starts_with('x'), ~ c(., mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
```

Result:

| -- | SECTFUND | GEO_DESC | x2008 | x2009 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BES | NT | NA | 0.75 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 6 | result | MEAN_top5 | 1.45 | 1.28 |
| 7 | GOV | NT | NA | 0.68 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 12 | result | MEAN_top5 | 0.65 | 0.765 |
| 13 | TOTAL | NT | 1.62 | 1.67 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 18 | result | MEAN_top5 | 2.44 | 2.39 |

How to return the values ​​column[c(6,12,18),1] with their respective Tags?

Example:

column[6.1]<-BES_result

column[12.1]<-GOV_result

column[18.1]<-TOTAL_result

I know that I could individually use the df["rowName", "columnName"] <- value option for each case. But, how to apply this idea following %>% above reported?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current code, create the 'result' row by `paste`ing the `first` value of 'SECTFUND' and then use `str_detect` to return the 'result' row

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
 group_by(SECTFUND) %>% 
   summarise(GEO_DESC = c(as.character(GEO_DESC), 'MEAN_top5'), 
       SECTFUND = c(as.character(SECTFUND), str_c(first(SECTFUND), '_result')), 
             across(starts_with('x'),
        ~ c(., mean(., na.rm = TRUE))), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  filter(str_detect(SECTFUND, 'result'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  SECTFUND     GEO_DESC  x2008 x2009
  <chr>        <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 BES_result   MEAN_top5  1.45 1.28 
2 GOV_result   MEAN_top5  0.65 0.765
3 TOTAL_result MEAN_top5  2.44 2.39
```

---

It is not clear why we need to `c`oncatenate first.  This can be done more directly

```
df %>% 
   group_by(SECTFUND) %>%
   summarise(GEO_DESC = 'MEAN_top5', SECTFUND = str_c(cur_group(), 
      '_result'), across(starts_with('x'), mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
        .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  SECTFUND     GEO_DESC  x2008 x2009
  <chr>        <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 BES_result   MEAN_top5  1.45 1.28 
2 GOV_result   MEAN_top5  0.65 0.765
3 TOTAL_result MEAN_top5  2.44 2.39
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the result to the original dataframe after summarising the result.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(SECTFUND) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with('x'), mean, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(SECTFUND = paste(SECTFUND, 'result', sep = '_'), 
         GEO_DESC = 'MEAN_top5') %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(SECTFUND)

#   SECTFUND     x2008  x2009 GEO_DESC  UNIT  
#   <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     <chr> 
# 1 BES          NA     0.75  NT        PC_GDP
# 2 BES          NA     2.02  SW        PC_GDP
# 3 BES           1.85 NA     ST        PC_GDP
# 4 BES           0.73  0.74  UK        PC_GDP
# 5 BES           1.76  1.63  US        PC_GDP
# 6 BES_result    1.45  1.28  MEAN_top5 NA    
# 7 GOV          NA     0.68  NT        PC_GDP
# 8 GOV          NA     0.92  SW        PC_GDP
# 9 GOV           0.62 NA     ST        PC_GDP
#10 GOV           0.49  0.54  UK        PC_GDP
#11 GOV           0.84  0.92  US        PC_GDP
#12 GOV_result    0.65  0.765 MEAN_top5 NA    
#13 TOTAL         1.62  1.67  NT        PC_GDP
#14 TOTAL         3.47  3.4   SW        PC_GDP
#15 TOTAL         2.71 NA     ST        PC_GDP
#16 TOTAL         1.61  1.67  UK        PC_GDP
#17 TOTAL         2.77  2.81  US        PC_GDP
#18 TOTAL_result  2.44  2.39  MEAN_top5 NA
```